# Buttons/Textfields inside xib view doesnt react when you copy paste?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to build several xib files for my project. I create a lot of xib files and some of them are nearly same with buttons/views/textfields. So I thought i can copy and paste the base view and delete unnecessary views/etc.
When I start the project the Buttons/Textfields doesn't react to touch.
The xib file is succesfully loaded /buttons/views/textfields are visible).
No view is in front of the Buttons/Textfields.
I tried also button.AddTarget().

Is there a reference that is copied with or is this just a bug and i have to build every xib file new?

Comment: You need to reset its touch methods if you copied paste that is also copied so you need to set to view controller where you paste it.

Comment: I added in the last view the addTarget method.
In the other views i added the button function with @IBAction func btnPressed(_ sender: Any)

Comment: While copying, all the IBOutlets and IBAction connected with those controls also get copied. You need to remove them and reconnect to the new ones accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
The problem was not because i copied the views the problem was that I center the content inside the xib and not binding top, bottom, leading and trailing.

This helped a lot.
[Some part of the screen is not clickable in SWIFT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27832907/some-part-of-the-screen-is-not-clickable-in-swift)